# "mysql -u root" doesn't work after upgrade from 5.6 to 5.7 on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04, which upgraded MySQL from 5.6 to 5.7.

I previously did not have a root password (it's just a local dev virtual machine). I'm unable to do "mysql -u root" as an unprivileged user, but when I change to the root ubuntu user, I can launch the mysql client without any problems. The mysql binary is the same for both users, so there's no trickery going on there.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo -u root -i
root@ubuntu:~# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 7
Server version: 5.7.12-0ubuntu1 (Ubuntu)
```

Changing the host settings (localhost vs. 127.0.0.1) has no impact. The contents of the mysql.user table are:

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| Host      | User             | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Reload_priv | Shutdown_priv | Process_priv | File_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv | Show_db_priv | Super_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Lock_tables_priv | Execute_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv | Create_view_priv | Show_view_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv | Create_user_priv | Event_priv | Trigger_priv | Create_tablespace_priv | ssl_type | ssl_cipher | x509_issuer | x509_subject | max_questions | max_updates | max_connections | max_user_connections | plugin                | authentication_string                     | password_expired | password_last_changed | password_lifetime | account_locked |
+-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| localhost | root             | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            | Y                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | auth_socket           |                                           | N                | 2016-05-04 21:46:45   |              NULL | N              |
| ubuntu    | root             | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            | Y                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password |                                           | N                | 2016-05-04 21:46:45   |              NULL | N              |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            | Y                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password |                                           | N                | 2016-05-04 21:46:45   |              NULL | N              |
+-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
```

Any ideas on how to better debug what's going on here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem!

During the upgrade, MySQL adds the [`auth_socket`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/socket-authentication-plugin.html) plugin type. This adjustment means that when connecting to localhost, I can't just simply add the "-uroot" flag and expect it to work, since MySQL compares the current user's name to the requested mysql name. A more helpful error message from MySQL would have been nice here.

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/socket-authentication-plugin.html):

> If a user on the local host with a login name of stefanie invokes `mysql` with the option `--user=valerie` to connect through the socket file, the server uses `auth_socket` to authenticate the client. The plugin determines that the `--user` option value (`valerie`) differs from the client user's name (`stephanie`) and refuses the connection. If a user named `valerie` tries the same thing, the plugin finds that the user name and the MySQL user name are both `valerie` and permits the connection. However, the plugin refuses the connection even for `valerie` if the connection is made using a different protocol, such as TCP/IP.

Comment: To revert this to the "old" way of doing things, just execute the follwoing SQL statement after connecting to the mysql instance as the system's actual root user (like shown in the question): 

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-p` flag won't help unless you have a password set for your account. You will have to [reset your root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Comment: There isn't a password on the account though - the fact that I can just use `mysql` as the root user shows that. I just don't understand why it works as the root shell user, but not with `mysql -uroot`

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using `mysql -uroot`, all one word, or possibly `mysql -uroot -p`, which would give you an option to enter a password or set one.

Comment: This isn't an answer, and shouldn't be posted as one. Once you've gained sufficient reputation to earn the comment privilege, you can leave comments to the question as *suggestions*. This space is for answers to the question, not suggestions about what you would do. Using the answer space to work around not having the comment privilege is not appropriate.

Comment: Honestly asking, would you have been fine with this if I had just said "use `mysql -uroot` ..." instead of "I would suggest using `mysql -uroot`..."? Because this was intended as an answer, insofar as the original question asked for "ideas to try and debug what's going on here". I usually see `mysql -uroot` instead of `mysql -u root`, and responded to that effect. If you want to argue that the implied question was really "what is the correct way to launch the MySQL client as an unprivileged user?", then I'll admit my answer was a bit underdeveloped, but I was responding to the actual wording.

Comment: I would have been fine if you had phrased it more as an answer than a suggestion, and had included additional details as to why that would be the solution. You offered a suggestion instead.

Comment: There's no password on the root account - see how I can just type `mysql` as the root user and log in that way. The spacing doesn't help either (`mysql -uroot`). I just don't understand why I can access mysql using the root shell user, but not with `mysql -uroot`.